# Unable to read series point values

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying yo identify series points which are under `0` and then put the bar in RED.

The following loop should do the trick but it throw an error :

```
For i = 1 To cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
        If (cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values(i) < 0) Then cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next i
```

where cht is :

```
Set cht = Ws.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart
```

The thrown error is :

> Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object

When the execution stop, the following line of code is highlighted :

```
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values(i)
```

I also tried :

```
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Values(i) < 0
```

Data Set :
X axis =

```
18.3 
11.5
6.1 
4.2
1.8
```

Y axis =

```
-1.2
-4.8
-9.6
 17.8 
 0.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close; the issue is with `.Points(i).Format.ForeColor.RGB`, which should be:

```
.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

For more readability, try something like the following:

```
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = Ws.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart

Dim s As Series
Set s = cht.FullSeriesCollection(1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To s.Points.Count
    If s.Values(i) < 0 Then
        s.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    End If
Next
```

Sample Chart:

[image]

Sample Chart 2:

[image]

Comment: Still same error, seems that `If (cht.SeriesCollection(1).Values(i) < 0)` throw the error

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Added code that works perfectly for me with a sample bar chart. I'd also avoid the inline `If`.

Comment: I added dataset in my post

Comment: Try changing the `If` to multi-line syntax as demonstrated in my answer. Is there still an error and if so, which line throws it?

Comment: `If cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values(i) < 0 Then` throw the error

Comment: I tried with `If s.Values(i) < 0 Then` still same error, does this work with the data set I just give ?

Comment: Big Ben got it If I store cht.SeriesCollection(1) in `Dim s As Series` it does work weird issue again. (to reproduce it on ur example delete `Dim s As Series`